# Listview with ImageButton, want to call Listview Click in ImageButton click Listener

Tags: listview, onclick, imagebutton

I managed to get my Listview rows populated with Image buttons and
since i added

> android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

to the row.xml, I can have both click listeners (ImageButton and Listview row)

but in a special case, I now want the Listview click listener to react also to the ImageButton click area. (simply as if the Imagebutton was not there) Is that possible?

**fragment.java:**

```
myList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            doRowOnClickStuff();
            return true;
        }
        });
```

**listAdapter.java**

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {Charakter charakter = (Charakter) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false);
    }

    TextView heading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
    final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupimagebutton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
    //in some cases, I want to call the Listview click listener and not imageButton click listener
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no idea if this is really a good practice, but it works like this:

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        ExpandableListView myList = (ExpandableListView) parent.findViewById(R.id.expandableList);// get reference to the ExpandableListView
        myList.performItemClick(view, myList.getPositionForView(view), getGroupId(groupPosition));
    }
});
```